# No audio from AVPlayer when pulling from URL

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, web, avplayer

Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here. First time working with Swift. Trying to play a simple audio file.

```
// Imports I need
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var isPlaying = false // variable to control playback selection, used in togglePlayPause

    var player = AVPlayer()

    // A button I have in the center of the View Controller
    @IBOutlet weak var PlayButton: UIButton!

    // A method that toggles playback when that button is hit
    // This SEEMS to work. Everything except audio playing and pausing seems to be working
    // when I debug
    @IBAction func togglePlayPause(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (isPlaying) {
            player.pause()
            PlayButton.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)    // This works
            print("Pause")                                                  // and this
        } else {
            player.play()
            PlayButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)   // This works
            print("Play")                                                   // and so does this
        }
        isPlaying = !isPlaying          // I do end up swapping each time this runs. I have
                                        // Breakpoints set up on the first statements of each
                                        // and I hit the opposite one each time I press the button
                                        // Oh, and the text on the button changes accordingly
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //let url = "http://192.99.131.205:8000/stream.mp3" // This is a Shoutcast stream.
                                                            // Not using it for now
        let url = "http://www.nasa.gov/mp3/640149main_Computers%20are%20in%20Control.mp3"
                                                            // Normal MP3 file from the web
        player = AVPlayer(URL: (NSURL(string: url))!)       // This SHOULD make an AVPlayer
                                                            // that connects to said URL and
        player.play()                                       // this should play it
        isPlaying = true                                    // Keep track
        PlayButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal) // Set button text
        player.volume = 1                                   // FORCE VOLUME FULL JUST IN CASE
    }

    // I honestly could remove this
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

So, what's wrong? Well, on my iPhone 5, running 8.3, at least, I get a network loading indicator in the top left corner of my screen, but no audio. It acts like it's TRYING to play, but no sound comes out of my device.

I really have no idea why this isn't working. I've seen other examples work and they were exactly this. I could unde3rstand that Shoutcast/Icecast streams require more work, but this is just a freaking static MP3 file.

I have AVFoundation and CFNetwork compiling with my app. I don't think I need CFNetwork, but oh well.

I'm targeting 8.3, running the latest xcode (Just downloaded it yesterday) and am building on a VM of 10.11.4. I would update my iPhone, but I can't right now.